# BGE Scripting minimap issue

Tags: scripting, game-engine

I am doing minimap and with script it should show You-are-here point with current position
the only problem is - the red point is always shown outside of the minimap region, although it is moving correctly.
but it should be on the location of a minimap!

what should i add to the simple code?
screenshot attached
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a blend file? This screenshot doesn't provide enough information, like the scene structure, what exactly is the `globalDict["Pos"]` (a list? If so, why dividing it?), etc.

Comment: sorry for the size. Character from Scenebasic sceneuses script1 and the red pointer from HUD Screen scene uses script2. You may wait for up to a minute when press P. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KxQPyPqYQFPLVRw-2kdhVNrswGzgyKQx

Comment: . in script1 i take worldposition xy axes of a Character and save it to a global variable Pos.

Comment: provided blend file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried your blend file, but it's too heavy to work with. I've made an example file exclusively to answer your question. [Download it here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1spjJ_EFhdaSYHClHiDP0l9CS2U6yx2o5).

What you need to create a minimap is understand the concept of a viewport and make both minimap and game map the same size, so the dot position will work as expected.

[image]

## How It Works

The basic concept of a minimap is:

- Create a *Minimap* scene, and the minimap object must be the same size as the game map. In this example, both have 200 meters on each side (delimited by the black borders).

[image]

- Add the *Minimap* as overlay scene.

[image]

- Set the viewport from *Minimap* scene's camera. Everything is detailed on the script `minimap.py`.

```py
# Enable viewport use on map camera
camera.useViewport = True

# Pre process the viewport pixel coordinates
left = getWindowWidth() // 2
bottom = getWindowHeight() // 2
right = getWindowWidth()
top = getWindowHeight()

# Set viewport coordinates
camera.setViewport(left, bottom, right, top)
```

- Store the player's *position* and *rotation* on `globalDict`.

```py
# Store player position and rotation on globalDict
globalDict['position'] = list(own.worldPosition)
globalDict['rotation'] = list(own.localOrientation.to_euler())
```

- Update the arrow representation from minimap based on values from globalDict.

```py
# Check if values are present in globalDict
if 'position' in globalDict.keys() and 'rotation' in globalDict.keys():

    # Update arrow's position and rotation
    own.worldPosition = globalDict['position']
    own.localOrientation = globalDict['rotation']
```

## Additional Notes

- Every object from *Game* scene is a group instance from scene *_LibScenery*.
- The *Minimap* is added as overlay scene automatically at game start on object *PlayerCollision* from scene *_LibScenery*.

Comment: thank you. but how do i set the camera so high that to have the whole gameworld in aerial perspective like in your example? My gameworld is big and when i set the camera high, it stops showing anything on some altitude

Comment: @ArtemKuzmin Simply increase the camera clipping distance (Properties editor > Camera tab > Set to Orthographic and Clipping End to to a high value).

Comment: thank you. i am doing something similar right now. could you probably help with this - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146546/blender-2-79-camera-ortho-doesnt-show-some-roofs-but-top-ortho-view-does

Comment: hey could you tell me please how i can change moving the player from WASD keys to updownleftright keys

Comment: @ArtemKuzmin Go to the scene _LibScenery and switch the layers to find the original player, the one on the game scene is just a group instance.

Comment: hey man i mentioned you in my Acknowledgement section here for my thesis. thanks. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ehDAAdBpWApNsSO-4U3joegglQrTq4uT