# Blender 2.79 Camera ortho doesn't show some roofs. But top ortho view does

Tags: camera

Camera ortho doesn't show some roofs, although each building has a roof.
Tried to flip normals, doesn't work.
All the roofs are displayed in top ortho perspective
Tried Clipping, doesn't work
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the clipping *of the camera*? (clip start/end) in the camera's properties. I don't know if the clipping you talk about is the view clipping or the cam's one.

Comment: Do you have an example file? I can only think of start camera clipping distance value too high or something related to materials.

Comment: Default view clipping is 1km and default for cam is 100m

Comment: please have a look. i tried. sorry for the size (130mb) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MixaBK77R_i8R6Mwlv1IapOr1ehscmeW

Comment: You could have zipped it, but whatever... I'm downloading it to take a look what's going on.

Comment: Move the camera up a bit (around z = 380 for instance), lower orthographic scale in the cam properties (around 900) and set end clipping around 1000.

Comment: yes, that works for the ortho camera, thanks. but it doesnt' work for the minimap on HUD Screen :( it keeps skipping some roofs although i changed the numbers as you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is mainly due to the camera Z position which is below top roofs (and so due to some limitation can't see them).

[image]

Move your camera up.

And adjust the following values:

[image]

Comment: yes, thanks. i did exactly the same steps! but minimap from the HUD screen keeps displaying incorrect, you may check or show me the correct representation of the minimap :(

Comment: @ArtemKuzmin All seem ok here. What is incorrect?

Comment: sorry, i see it. the texture of my minimap is incorrect and was done from the old ortho camera image that didn't show the roofs! thanks

Comment: If needed adjust the values of what is in green in the image above.

Comment: one last thing here i am struggling with. I would like to put a pointer on the minimap to show the building the character should reach. once he has reached the building, the pointer should disappear (aka task completed). I have put a yellow pointer on the minimap, created property next1, send message as soon as ne is near the building. but the pointer is not displayed on the minimap in the game, although i of course moved it on Z axe :( so that yellow rectangular is not displaying for some reason https://drive.google.com/open?id=18_ps1NR1y7hkZkp3cuD34zQEMQD1OI8U

Comment: @ArtemKuzmin You should ask another question as I'm not familiar at all with the game engine (as I presume this what you need to use for that).

Comment: hey i mentioned you in my acknowledgement section in my thesis. thanks man. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ehDAAdBpWApNsSO-4U3joegglQrTq4uT

Comment: @ArtemKuzmin, thanks, nice to do that.